# How can I compare object values inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am wondering how I can compare values within an array.

Here are two arrays:

```
var noRepeatStore = [];
var store = [
  {name: "a"},
  {name: "b"},
  {name: "c"},
  {name: "b"},
  {name: "a"}
];
```

If the `name` value is unique it should return true and push the non-repeated object to a new array.

The expected result:

```
noRepeatStore = [{name:"a"}, {name:"b"}, {name:"c"}];
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `is the a way to achieve this?` Have you made any attempt yourself yet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ng Sheng Kee.  Please read the help section about how to ask good questions, and note that showing something you have tried is considered good form here.

Comment: With that said, look at this function from a popular utility library: https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/Array/unique

Comment: This fix my issue! Thanks!